# DIALOGFLOW ES error "Entity '...' has an invalid name."

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using the Dialogflow ES UI to train my agents, since last week I see this validation error in some of my entities *"Entity 'entity-name' has an invalid name."* in ALL my agents.

I'm not sure what the error message means since you can't edit the name of a system entity.
[image]

If I click on "Edit entity" it goes bonkers and shows an error message that makes no sense to me:
[image]

This is what sys.given-name looks like. I don't see what's wrong, I even downloaded the JSON file and can't find anything that looks out of place.
[image]

After deleting all the entries in the entity the error still persist. I'm pretty sure this is a bug but I don't know where to report it. Help please!!

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is affecting the way my agent is detecting this entities, resulting in bad intent matching :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully replicated your error and this is because you have entries (mercedes, roque, lourdes) in your `sys.given-name`.
[image]

To remove the error, you must first delete all entries on your `sys.given-name`, remove all `sys.given-name` entity from all affected **Intents** and then delete the `sys.given-name` from the **Entities** tab.

Once `sys.given-name` is not in **Entities** tab anymore, you can now use `sys.given-name` in your intent similar to below sample walkthrough. Please note that in my example below, I will be using `sys.person` instead of `sys.given-name` since per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities), `sys.given-name` and `sys.last-name` are both deprecated and must use `sys.person` instead.

1. In your **Intent**, add training phrase/s and then double-click on the **name** and then assign the `sys.person`.
   [image]
2. In the **Action and parameters**, input the *parameter name*, **entity** and *value* based on the values on step 1.
   [image]
3. Add a response and use the parameter for your `sys.person`.
   [image]
4. You can now test and use any names and it should be captured.
   [image]

Do the same steps if you have also a validation error on `sys.last-name`. Once done, there should be no more error on your **Validation** tab.

Comment: I've been using these entities for a year now and it didn't occur to me that they might've become deprecated. The documentation contradicts itself when it suggests you can extend sys.person for uncommon names when at the same time states this entity is not extendable but I guess I don't have a choice but to use it. Thank you for you help!